# require node modules written in coffeescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

I have two files, one is a controller and another is a test for this controller, both are in coffeescript and are in the same folder:

The folder structure is:

```
-controller
    --labels.controller.coffee
    --labels.controller.spec.coffee
```

The `labels.controller` extract:

```
module.exports = {
  getImages: getImages
}
```

I am trying to require it from labels.controller.spec to test it

I tried

```
labelsController = require('labels.controller')
```

and

```
labelsController = require('./labels.controller')
```

and

```
labelsController = require('/labels.controller')
```

But always there is an error like:

```
Error: Cannot find module '../labels.controller'
```

What I am doing wrong? Is any difference if you include a file written in coffeescript?

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile it first with the `coffee` command. In your project source, run this command (assuming your project is written in coffeescript)

```
coffee -co output/ src/
```

Where `src` is your project folder. Then run the `.js` files in `output` with `node`.